# Default location of ChromeDriver binary and Chrome binary on windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

What is the default location of ChromeDriver binary and Chrome binary on windows 7 for triggering appium using java-client.jar? if i am using RemoteWebDriver and tries to initiate chrome browser, from where does the selenium initiates the chromedriver?

the code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("userName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileUsername"));
capabilities.setCapability("password", ReadProperties.Properties("MobilePassword"));
capabilities.setCapability("udid", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileUID"));
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileBrowser"));
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobilePlatform"));
log.Info(capabilities.getVersion());
mobile_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(""+ReadProperties.Properties("MobileURL")+"/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

Answer (score 4):

**chromedriver** is not installed in your System by default. Users individually have to download **chromedriver** from [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page and you can place it anywhere within your system.

You must ensure that **Chrome** is installed at the optimum location as the server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for each system as per the snapshot below :

[image: Chrome_Location]

**Note** : For Linux systems, the *ChromeDriver* expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. You can also override the Chrome binary location following the documentation [Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location).

Answer (score 0):

The location will depend on your default download folder e.g. when you download something from the internet and it goes into the downloads folder, then that is your default download folder.

So if you downloaded chromedriver.exe the same way, then it will also be in the downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3rd party service to run your tests you should not care about chromedriver.

But when you run tests locally you have to download it yourself: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
And then use capability to set absolute path to this file.
Make sure you use chromedriver version compatible with your browser version.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but none of the answers above helped me. I found a different solution that worked for me and it might help someone else in the future.

I have tried the below solution with only Windows 10 / Server 2016.

Step 1: Get to the Google Chrome install directory by right clicking on the Chrome icon and click on Properties. You will see the installed directory listed under 'Target' and 'Start in' options. The directory path should end with .../Chrome/Application/. Copy the whole path.

Step 2: Open File Explorer and go to the above copied path. You should see chrome.exe file with other files and folders. Copy the whole Application/ folder including chrome.exe file with other files and folders.

Step 3: Go to the below file path and paste the above Application folder.

> C:\Users<YOUR USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\

After pasting the Application folder, you should have the chrome.exe file with other files and folders in the following file path:

> C:\Users<YOUR USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\

Now the ChromeDriver should be able to locate the Chrome Binary.