# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when i go to command prompt and type chromedriver -v:

```
ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614})
```

but when i try to run this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver 
class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("www.instagram.com")
InstaBot()
```

it gives me error like this:
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

why this is happening i tried to remove selenium as well as chromedriver 
and reinstall of version 79.0.3945 but when i run it ,it show this can only be run on version 80
my chrome version is 79.0.3945 which is lastest ,and version 80 chrome is chrome beta

Comment: Selenium is finding a different chromedriver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v80.0* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You mentioned about using *chromedriver=79.0.3945.36* and the release notes of *chromedriver=79.0* clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v79**

- Presumably you are using *chrome v79.0* browser.
- So, it's quite evident your have **chromedriver=80.0** present within your system which is also within the system `PATH` variable and is invoked while you:

  ```
  self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
  ```

---

### Solution

There are two solutions:

- Either you upgrade *chrome* to **Chrome Version 80.0** level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))
- Or you can override the default **chromedriver v80.0** binary location with **chromedriver v79.0** binary location as follows:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Ubuntu: selenium.common.exceptions: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438332/ubuntu-selenium-common-exceptions-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromed/59454235#59454235)

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure to:

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Answer (score -1):

Use Bonigarcia plugin in project. After that it will manage all driver by itself.It reads chrome version and instantiate driver accordingly.

for help follow my post :
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/webdrivermanager-bonigarcia-rohan-ravi-yadav/

or original git link/post
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

If any help required , Let me know