# ChromeDriver v80 doesn't work even though Chrome version is matched (Chrome v80)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

chromedriver.exe file is in the folder it works.

the version is 80.0.3987.116. also the chrome's version is 80.0.3987.116.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

this doesn't work. with that error message.

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

I thought this error is because of updating chrome hours ago

Then I changed my code with chromeoptions

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options= chrome_options)
```

also doesn't work with another error.

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

The version is matched with chrome version.

I tried installing a different version of chromedriver and got the same error.

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v80* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** where is version is other then 80.0.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You mentioned about using *chromedriver=80* and *chrome=80* but somehow while your program execution *ChromeDriver* other then **v80** is being invoked.
- So, it's quite evident your have other versions of *ChromeDriver* other then **chromedriver=81.0** present within your system and is present within the system `PATH` variable which gets invoked while you:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```

---

### Solution

The easiest solution will be to override the default **chromedriver** binary location with **chromedriver v80.0** binary location as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621700/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea/59624419#59624419)
- [Ubuntu: selenium.common.exceptions: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438332/ubuntu-selenium-common-exceptions-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromed/59454235#59454235)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by updating the Chrome Webdriver version using - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/
hope it helps !!
Thanks.