# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 25979
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'ANUDEEP', ip: '192.168.43.250', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at Pharma.Sales.main(Sales.java:14)




    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ANUDEEP\\Desktop\\Selenium_IHealthpharm\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.ihealthpharm.com");




    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUserName")).sendKeys("suhan54");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginPassword")).sendKeys("123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: when i have update the browser getting same error..like if i have update version 80.. it showing driver only supports version 80

Comment: Just posting the error won't be enough. Add some context around it

Comment: @abhiarora are you able see the context now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)