# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So this is my first time working with selenium, and I get the chromedriver browser to open fo a quarter of a second and then it closes, even it I give it a webpage to load or I tell it to sleep. It also gives me a SessionNotCreatedException.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class TestBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Error:

```
>>> bot = TestBot()

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55101/devtools/browser/7029bc33-860f-42b8-8fb5-751cf27f82bc
[16708:17644:0524/045808.952:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test_bot.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\test_bot\test_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\test_bot\test_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\test_bot\test_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\test_bot\test_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\test_bot\test_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
```

I've tried adding Chromedriver as a path variable and that didn't work. I can start a chromedriver session just fine in cmd.

Comment: Are you sure you have tha latest chromedriver?

Comment: @GiorgosKavalieratos I am using chromedriver version 83.0.4103.39 along with chrome verion 83.0.4103.61 which supports chrome version 83

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try running Selenium with MozillaFirefox,you also will need to install Geckodriver, which is a software that acts as a bridge between Firefox and selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong version of chrome, turns out I have version 81, so I installed webdriver-manager and that works

Answer (score 0):

as we see in the last line:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
```

try to:

- update Chrome to last version so selenium too
- use `geckodriver.exe` for chrome , and put inside a folder then try:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\your\geckodriver\path\withput\")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Analysis

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *ChromeDriver 83.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver 83.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 83**

Most possibly the *Chrome Browser* haven't been updated to [**Chrome v83.0**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83) yet as a part of the recent push and still is [**Chrome v81.0**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/04/nic81)

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v83.0* and the *Chrome Browser v81.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.