# SessionNotCreatedException only support Chrome version 80

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code below and it throw the SessionNotCreatedException on the last line.

```
chrome_options = Options()
LANG = 'fr,fr_FR'
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': LANG})
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

> SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80

However, I am already using version 80 ! Downloaded here : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/

Answer (score 1):

Alternative which worked : [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)

However, the silent log mode doesn't work...

```
os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
```