# I'm getting error when ever i automate the code browser opened and then suddenly closing

Tags: selenium

session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-GRB5533T', ip: '192.168.43.182', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: Add some code or reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your chrome driver version, time to time chrome driver exe is updating based on your browser version, check your chrome browser version and downloaded chrome driver exe version according to your browser version

You can download latest driver exe from here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: download driver exe and set path and refresh project and rerun it will work, if its not let me know