# ValueError: There is no such driver by url

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am using Selenium on a mac with Apple M2 chip and since 10 days I keep getting the following error (initially I did not have this error but I changed computers and now I can no longer use Selenium) :

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/106.0.5249/chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip
```

I read the following threads about this issue:

https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/JRuQzH3qr2c?pli=1

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/443

But I fail to understand how to fix this problem.

I tried updating webdriver-manager but I still get the same error.

I also downloaded the latest release of chromedriver here https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ but then fail to understand what to do next.

Any help or comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue, I corrected this way

```
python3 -m pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade

python3 -m pip install packaging
```

Comment: Just 
pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade - works for me

Answer (score 13):

You have to switch to version 114.0.5735.90. Because the end point to download version 115.0.5790.102 has changed and chrome driver manager is not yet updated. Thus the below code should work.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install()))
```

Answer (score 7):

found this here - https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/pull/445

```
pip uninstall webdriver_manager
pip install git+https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager@master
```

Comment: thank you very much I tried but unfortunately it returns the same error ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/106.0.5249.61/chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip

Comment: yep same issue for me too

Comment: Seems the latest working hasn't been merged to main branch yet. Install this `pip install git+https://github.com/david-engelmann/webdriver_manager.git@de-upgrade-chrome-version` and worked well.

Comment: @SarachaTongkumpunt: tried this but still the same error.

Comment: @NageshSinghChauhan Just tried again today and failed. Fixed with:
pip uninstall webdriver_manager
pip install git+https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager@master

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(driver_version='114.0.5735.90').install())

Answer (score 3):

use version argument in the ChromeDriverManager

```
webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(driver_version='114.0.5735.90').install(), 
options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Now this returns
/n

```TypeError: ChromeDriverManager.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
```

Comment: @ScottMoore The parameter has been renamed to `driver_version` in the latest release.

Comment: This solution will give above error what Scott mentioned. Please recreate the scenario and provide answer which works in maximum cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I corrected this way

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(driver_version='114.0.5735.90').install())
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install())
```

Comment: I just uninstall and reinstall webdriver_manager. ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90') needs to change to ChromeDriverManager(driver_version='114.0.5735.90')

Answer (score 1):

Try this while scraping using selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install()),options=option)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome ver 115 by updating the webdriver-manager to 4.0.0

With this package update the old syntax

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
```

started to work again :)

Comment: I changed requirements.txt to show 4.0.1 and updated my Chrome browser to version 118.0.5993.70
It works with old syntax!

Answer (score 1):

I confronted the same issue; however, I was able to resolve it by upgrading the webdriver-manger:

```
python3 -m pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads
Current Releases
If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard. This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to change the requirements.txt to show 4.0.1 instead of the 3.8.x version it was originally referencing. Even though I had 4.0.1 installed, it was still messing up.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! I changed requirements.txt to show 4.0.1
and updated my Chrome browser to version 118.0.5993.70

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Updating your own chrome broswer version might also be helpful in some cases, accordingly to version 4.0.0 of `webdriver_manager` if your version is below 113 it might solve the issue....

link for update [chrome://settings/help](https://chrome://settings/help)