# ValueError: There is no such driver by url version=114.0.5735.90

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was having an issue with [ValueError: There is no such driver by url]. I looked at another thread another thread ([ValueError: There is no such driver by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011776/valueerror-there-is-no-such-driver-by-url)) to try to find a solution.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install()))
```

However, the solutions that the other thread found (Forcing the ChromeDriverManager to v114) gave me another error message [Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path]. I tried changing the version to 116.0.5845.97, but then it brought back the [ValueError: There is no such driver by url] message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='116.0.5845.97').install()))
```