# What is the relationship between chrome binary and chrome driver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

When I use chrome driver, is it equivalent to using chrome driver to call chrome binary？

[chrome binary](https://chrome://version) path：
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Question background：
When I use wdio test my project, I configure the binary parameter of goog: chromeOptions .
When I filled in chromedriver path。and I got exception

> Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.

Comment: Can you check whether your Chrome driver and Chrome binary have matching versions? Probably the Chrome binary is newer so something doesn't match?

Comment: @qrsngky I'm pretty sure. they are same version. In fact, I install current version after I remove all chromedriver in my computer.more detail:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180402/why-it-show-me-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-104