# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, version, win64

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: chromedriver 113.0.5672.63 for WIN64 not found in http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue by updating the WebDriverManager in the POM file with the latest one. Which help to auto-update the ChromeDriver version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```