# Selenium error: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

Would appreciate some help on this.

- I downloaded CHROMEDRIVER
- Copied it to python path in my system

While I try to invoke CHROME browser and set an executable path under Pycharm, I get the below error.

code ---   **driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\Users\vinayak.gulati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\chromedriver.exe")**

Error I get ---- **selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83**

Thanks.

Comment: something similar happened to me once... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621700/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea) solved the problem

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

Your `Chrome Driver` version needs to match your `Chrome Browser` version

1. Get you Chrome Browser version, by typing `chrome://version`

2. Download Chrome Driver version that matches you Chrome Browser version, form this website 
   https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: I used this as a starting point for my needs. I ended up checking for version like Asad does and then: `npm i -D chromedriver@~83` for my CucumberJS project.

Comment: No, it's not saying that! It says the driver support chrome 83. don't confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply downgrade your `chromedriver` to work with your current `Chrome` version.

OR

Update the **Google Chrome** version to **83** will also do the job.

**Steps:**
1. Go to Help -> About Google Chrome -> Chrome will automatically look for updates(update Chrome to the latest version)

[image]

Update it and if it displays version `83.x.x.x.x.x.` then it should solve your problem.